# Change executing file prefix on Makefile

Tags: unix, makefile, gnu-make

Given this markdown:

```
MARKDOWN=$(shell find src -iname "*.md")

HTML=$(MARKDOWN:src%.md=dist%.html)

all: $(HTML)

%.html:
    #do the processing here
```

I can change the prefixes and suffixes of the files on the HTML variable.
But when I'm executing the build I would like to change it back to use the markdown on the script.

I would like something like this:

```
%.html: src%.md
     pandoc --from markdown --to html $< -o $@
```

Until now I was able to change the suffix, but not the prefix.
How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given your definition of the `HTML` variable:

```
HTML=$(MARKDOWN:src%.md=dist%.html)
```

The rule `%.html: src%.md` won't match the expansion of `HTML`, since the *stem* (i.e.: the `%` part) had to contain `dist` for the target but not for the prerequisite. Instead, the rule has to be changed to:

```
dist%.html: src%.md
```